# Updated: Initialise and Clear multiple hash in one line

Tags: perl

How can I Initialise and clear multiple hash in one line.

Ex:

```
my %hash1 = ();
my %hash2 = ();
my %hash3 = ();
my %hash4 = ();
```

to

```
my ( %hash1, %hash2, %hash3, %hash4 ) = ?
```

Comment: You do not *need* to clear hashes that have just been created. They are already created empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears (from your comments) that you really want to empty hashes that already have stuff in them. You can do it like this:

```
(%hash1,%hash2,%hash3) = ();
```

Complete example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash1 = ('foo' => 1);
my %hash2 = ('bar' => 1);
my %hash3 = ('baz' => 1);

(%hash1,%hash2,%hash3) = ();

print (%hash1,%hash2,%hash3);
```

A variable declaration always gives you an empty variable, so there is no need to set it to empty.  This is true even in a loop:

```
for (0..100)
{
    my $x;
    $x++;
    print $x;
}
```

This will print `1` over and over; even though you might expect `$x` to retain its value, it does not.

**Explanation:** Perl allows list assignment like `($foo,$bar) = (1,2)`.  If the list on the right is shorter, any remaining elements get assigned `undef`.  Thus assigning the empty list to a list of variables makes them all undefined.

Another useful way to set a bunch of things is the `x` operator:

```
my ($x,$y,$z) = (100)x3;
```

This sets all three variables to 100.  It doesn't work so well for hashes, though, because each one needs a list assigned to it.

Comment: Thanks. Is it correct in case of hash as suggested by you. ` my (%hash1,%hash2,%hash3) = 4 x ();

Comment: @Sourcecode, you could use `() x 3`.  The thing you are assigning has to come first, and the count second.  However, there is no real reason to do this as `()` works just as well.

Comment: @Sourcecode No, the word you are looking for is "wrong". Applying the string multiplier `x` to the empty list to clear already empty variables is just to make a redundant thing even more redundant. Also, you reversed the order of the arguments: `4 x ()` means "take the number 4 and repeat it 0 times".

Answer (score 5):

It's as simple as doing

```
my ( %hash1, %hash2, %hash3, %hash4 );
```

and they will not contain any keys or values at that point.

The same technique applies to scalars and arrays.

To `undef` multiple hashes, you could do

```
undef %$_ for ( \%hash1, \%hash2 );
```

Comment: Let there be data in the 4 hash and I need to clear all the hash in one line,  So what I have to assign to the hashes.

Comment: Can a hash be undef? I've just noticed that printing a newly declared array or hash does not give any undefined warning.

Comment: @TLP: You can use `undef %hash`, which empties the hash rather than assigning an `undef` value to it. `undef $hash{key}` sets the value of the element to `undef`. The same applies to arrays.

Comment: @Borodin Exactly. I guess it is just a philosophical question, an empty hash is an empty hash, and you can do that with `undef`.

Comment: @TLP: Ah I see. Sorry, didn't intend to patronize you. The way I see it, assigning a value to a variable is said to *define* it, so `undef` returns any variable to the state where they haven't been defined, or assigned to.

Comment: @Borodin No problem. I was just surprised when I tried to print an empty hash and did not get a warning. I guess I haven't thought about it before, that they evaluate to an empty list, not an undefined value. It's something to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize it as:

my %hash1 = %hash2 = %hash3 = %hash4 = ();

Comment: No, you can't. You can only do that if you first declare hashes 2-4 on another line.

Comment: Well... Let's try to run something like: perl -e "my %hash1 = %hash2 = %hash3 = %hash4 = ( 'key1', 'value1', 'key2', 'value2', 'key3', 'value3' ); print %hash3;" And you'll get output with all declared values: key2value2key1value1key3value3

Comment: Not under `strict` it won't. You'll need to do something like `my %hash1 = my %hash2 = my %hash3...` which is an eyesore.

Comment: @AndreyTykhonov That would mean that you have declared only one variable, `%hash1`. The other variables are the package globals `%main::hash2`, `%main::hash3` and `%main::hash4`. They do not have the same scope.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to assign anything to a **new** variable in order to assure it is empty. All variables are empty, if nothing has been assigned to them.

```
my %hash;  # hash contains nothing
%hash = () # hash still contains nothing
```

The only time it would be *useful* to assign the empty list to a hash is if you want to remove previously assigned values. And even then, that would only be a useful thing to do if it could not already be solved by applying the *correct scope* restriction to the hash.

```
my (%hash1, %hash2);
while (something) {
    # some code
    (%hash1,%hash2) = ();   # delete old values
}
```

Emptying the hashes. Better written as:

```
while (something) {
    my (%hash1, %hash2);    # all values are now local to the while loop
    # some code
}
```